# Error generating ClickOnce deployement of a Net 5 app with Net Std 2.1 libraries

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2019, clickonce, .net-5, .net-standard-2.1

I recently started to develop a WPF project with Visual Studio 2019. (I'm new in the WPF world)

My solution has the next projects:

```
MyProject.App (net5.0-windows10.0.18362.0 .exe)

    Dependencies:
        Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
        Microsoft.NetCore.App
        Microsoft.WIndows.SDK.NET.Ref
        Microsoft.Windows.Desktop.App.WPF
        Newtonsoft.Json
        ModernWpfUI
        MyProject.Domain
        MyProject.Data
        MyProject.Services

MyProject.Domain netstandard2.1 .dll)

    Dependencies:
        NetStandard.Library

MyProject.Data (netstandard2.1 .dll)

    Dependencies:
        NetStandard.Library
        Dapper

MyProject.Services (netstandard2.1 .dll) 

    Dependencies:
        NetStandard.Library
        MyProject.Domain
        MyProject.Data
```

Nugget packages information:

- [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)
- [ModernWpfUI](https://github.com/Kinnara/ModernWpf)

When I try to publish the .App project using ClickOnce, I'm getting the next error:

> Publish has encountered an error.
> Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.

And the output says:

```
2>Metadata file 'F:\Projectes\X3\MyProject\MyProject.Data\bin\Release\net5.0-windows10.0.18362.0\MyProject.Data.dll' could not be found
2>Metadata file 'F:\Projectes\X3\MyProject\MyProject.Domain\bin\Release\net5.0-windows10.0.18362.0\MyProject.Domain.dll' could not be found
2>Metadata file 'F:\Projectes\X3\MyProject\MyProject.Services\bin\Release\net5.0-windows10.0.18362.0\MyProject.Services.dll' could not be found
```

It seems it is looking for my library projects at: `\net5.0-windows10.0.18362.0` directory, but in fact they are generated at: `\netstandard2.1` folder.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/293136/error-generating-clickonce-deployement-of-a-net-5.html) your question?  I will follows this question in Q&A platform.

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT yes, it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I found by now:

Edit publish profile file .pubxml:

Find actual  tag:

```
 <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.18362.0</TargetFramework>
```

and replace it by:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net5.0-windows10.0.18362.0;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>
```